# Ruby password SHA512 hash replication using PHP

Tags: php, ruby, hash, passwords, sha512

is there any way I can reproduce this ruby function:

```
def Password.hash(password,salt)
    Digest::SHA512.hexdigest("#{password}:#{salt}")
end
```

In php.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it, using the php [hash()](http://php.net/hash) function

```
function passwordhash($password, $salt)
{
   return hash('sha512', "{$password}:{$salt}");
}
```